# Can't remove default tooltip in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, tooltip, title

I want to use custom tooltip based on 'title' attribute, and try to remove default behavior. It works good in Firefox bot doesn't work in IE9.

I'm doing something like this:

```
 $(element).on('mouseover mouseout', '[title], [tipText]', function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
                        var org_elem = $(e.currentTarget);
                        var tipText = org_elem.attr('title');
                        org_elem.attr('tipText', tipText);
                        org_elem.removeAttr('title');
//then I create custom tooltip which based on tipText attribute
....
```

When I move mouse on element first time in IE9 both tooltip (default and custom) are displayed. All other times only custom tooltip displayed.

So how to prevent default tooltip in IE9?

Comment: It looks like you need to apply the custom tooltip when the HTML is loaded, removing the title attributes before the first mouseover happens, rather than after the first mouseover.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried leaving it empty?

```
org_elem.attr("title", "");
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the JQuery [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) attribute and methods instead. This is the kind of thing it's made for.

Instead of:

```
var tipText = org_elem.attr('title');
```

It would be something like:

```
var tipText = org_elem.data('title');
```

Your HTML would be:

```
<div data-title="text information that would show up on a tooltip"><div>
```

instead of:

```
<div title="text information that would show up on a tooltip"><div>
```

You actually wouldn't need the extra tipText attribute.